# How can I include common strings (regexes) in several projects written in different languages?

Tags: git, github, strings, import, golang

I have a simple Go library (~300 lines, mostly type declarations and nice methods and compatibility methods for gomobile etc., also pretty-printing scripts). The heart of the whole project are two regexes, placed in a separate file in my Go repository.

Now I want to port that simple library to Python, Java (Android), maybe Javascript. I want the regexes to rest in a single Git repository (maybe even the Golang one).

What is the best way to include the regexes at compile/build time as string constants? In case of Golang, it seems that the only way is to use `go generate`, which generates source code files and could include those regexes from a plain text file. So I decided to make a separate Go source code file for easy parsing by *other* build tools in case of Python, Java, Javascript. I would appreciate any advice how to do it efficiently that way. I could also make a *separate repository* for two regexes and use `git submodules` (or even treat it as a sepratate Go package in Go project).

But I've lost my hope for a pretty solution, and that's why I'm asking here and not on SO; how do you solve such problems? The simplest way would be to manually "cherry-pick" commits from each repository, setting author field manually.

Comment: Submodule is a quite universal way to get it done and good in practice. Also it allows for selective updating of every repository and testing updates in the regex before releasing.

Comment: @LucFranken Yeah, but a separate repository for two ~200 characters long lines?

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me at least). Are you porting a Go project to Python, or are you using Python and Go code in a single project?

Comment: Regex syntax isn't necessarily the same in all languages.  (Or even between regex libraries in the same language.)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede  I am using re2.

Comment: @gardenhead Porting. Maybe there would be some usage of a Python+Go server in Android app for historical database access, but mainly porting the library which uses changing URLs and the regexes — for parsing an undocumented website.

Comment: @ArchieT Yes why not, a repo is free and the case is you need it on compile time and in multiple languages. Git is just going to do that for you. Alternative would be a custom solution like a build script in each platform which takes the regex from a place (sounds like a repo already) and then pulls it in for you. Which basically equals the sub repo approach but then custom made. And you lost versioning by then.

Comment: @LucFranken Not necessarily. I could download that single file from existing Go GitHub repo in Python, Java and JavaScript build scripts, over `http://raw.githubusercontent.com`

Comment: If you have public access then yes you are right on that. As for example a js developer I would not be too happy on that because I have to find the right file in that repo but doable yes. I would go for a new repo anyway, include a read me file and it's clear what the purpose is. I also like that all language specific implementations work the same way after that move. And you have your issues and pull requests only on the algorithm not mixed with the go implementation. I think it boils down to preference from here.

Comment: @LucFranken Now I'm not sure whether I should use Git submodules or Go import in Go project.

Comment: I would go for git since that also works for your other languages you want to approach. In any language you can use a git sub module without a hassle because it's invisible for the language, it just inserts the file for you into the source.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple solution, but you could always put the regexes into a properties file, and then have the various code bases load their regexes as text values and compile them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one such project:

[image: golang regexp for minimal static site generator]

[image: javascript regexp for minimal static site generator]

[image: python regexp for minimal static site generator]

**References**

- [minimal/tools : minimal static site generator github repo](https://github.com/lutzroeder/minimal/tree/master/tools)